# Automated Row height in table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to expand my cell when there is extra text inputed. I do not want "..." at the end I would like the cell to automatically expand. I have taken these two steps below but it is not working.

[image]

Step 1

```
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Step 2

```
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

For some reason my cell is not expanding what am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


struct postStruct {
    let username : String!
    let message : String!
    let photoURL : String!
}



class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var generalRoomDataArr = [postStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension





    }


    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToRoom", sender: nil)
    }


    //Message Send button is pressed data uploaded to firebase
    @IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let message : String = self.messageTextField.text!



    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return generalRoomDataArr.count // your number of cell here
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {




        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")



        //Set message label to display message
        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0


        // your cell coding
        return cell!
    }





}//END CLASS
```

**UPDATE:**
    I have the current constraints but my dynamic cell growth is not working. My cell is still showing "..." Can anyone help me understand why? I tried reset to suggested constraints but it is not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey @nil are u doing this with the use of auto layout?

Comment: no i dont believe i am

Comment: please go through auto layout it'll make more easier for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've auto layout for the custom UITableViewCell. Change the **estimatedRowHeight**, try this:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
```

Comment: If you've custom label in your cell, please add the constraints/autolayout. As I was using the normal UITableViewCell, it worked for me :)

Comment: If you have a label added, select the label, pin and say,"Reset to suggested constraints"

Comment: can you go into more detail im kind of new to swift

Comment: Please post your screenshot from the storyboard.

Comment: posted the screen shot

Comment: Select the table view cell from your VC, below you see 4 pins (beside + button), tap on last pin, and say Reset to Suggested Constraints.

Comment: ok it worked but it made the image longate down and made it to big

Comment: Please accept the answer. Select image, tap on the 3rd pin and select width and height constraints & add those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method of UITableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
       return .AutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
       return 60
}
```

But first you must set the autolayout constraint for the label w.r.t to the content view of TableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.3

```
// MARK: - TableViewDelegate Setup

extension NotificationVC : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

   }
```

Comment: I have posted a update with a current problem can someone help me understand the issue.

Comment: can u post the project with particular problem u have now in git and share me that